# Excel error may be caused by pandas writing or big data? advise needed

Tags: python, excel, xml, pandas, dataframe

I am reading multiple xml files extracting some data then forming a pandas Dataframe with my data. These are the main steps that I do:

1. open an xml file
2. extract some elements
3. create a pandas dataframe with the extracted elements
4. append the results in the excel file named "output.xlsx"(using the code below in python)

My steps are repeated for all xml files that i have (15gb of initial data that usually have 100MB of valuable text data)

This is my python code for appending data frames in the output excel file:

```
book = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row
output.to_excel(writer, startrow=startrow,index = False, header = False)
writer.save()
```

When I open the "output.xlsx" in Excel, I receive a prompt message saying "We found a problem with some content in "output.xlsx". Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?" with a yes or no answer

This is the log file that excel generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"> 
<logFileName>error001280_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in 
 file 'D:\JUPYWORKDIR\2009Results\output.xlsx'</summary><repairedRecords> 
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: String properties from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
</repairedRecord></repairedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

I am worried that saving my results to excel format is corrupting my data, i will read "output.xlsx" with pandas in future in order to do some data analysis, does this problem effect my future analysis? I wanted to know why this problem is generated and should I save my data in CSV? any suggestions?

Ps. Checking the last row of "output.xlsx" using python code it is the same number of rows when i import the excel file in a pandas Dataframe, lastly checking the last row of the "recovered file" of Microsoft excel i still find the same number of rows so i think its a generic error of Microsoft excel because of large data but i am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its an excel problem handling big data because i opened the file with open office spreadsheets and it doesn't show any error

Comment: I have the same here. Opened with LibreOffice without any error.But the whole Excel file weighs 684 KB, it has two sheets, the longest one is 4000 rows long. That is not really large data.

Answer (score 11):

I also had the same issue and spent at least an hr searching to fix it, there was only 1 change and it got fixed, Instead of using writer.save(), try using writer.close() and it should resolve the issue.

Modified the above  mentioned code:

```
options = {}
options['strings_to_formulas'] = False
options['strings_to_urls'] = False
book = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl',options=options)
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row
output.to_excel(writer, startrow=startrow,index = False, header = False)
writer.close()
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  What is the point of writer.save() if the file is saved without it?